# SQL Server Mgmt Studio messing up my Database!

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

This has effectively ruined my day. I have a larger number of tables with many FK relationships in between. One of the tables (lets call it table A) has a computed column, which is computed via a UDF with schemabinding and is also fulltext indexed.

If I edit **any table** (lets call it table B) that in any way is related (e.g via FK) to the table with the fulltext indexed computed column (table A), and I save it, the following happens:

- Changes to the table (table B) are saved
- I get the error: "Column 'abcd' is no fulltext indexed." regarding table A which I didn't even edit, and then "User canceled out of save dialog"
- **All FK relationships to ALL TABLES from Table B are DELETED**

What the hell is going on??? Can someone explain to me how this can happen?

Comment: Management Studio has a feature that will show you the script it's going to run before applying any changes.  Have you checked that?

Comment: Do you have MSSQL SP1 installed (on the client - SQL Server Tools)?  I don't know that this would prevent the above, but has to be worth a try.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: It actually did delete the relationships even though data was present.
@Joel: No I haven't checked that yet...
@Will: I don't think I have MSSQL SP1... My SQL version is 10.0.2531.0

Comment: If that's your version of Management Studio then you have SP1 installed.  :(

Comment: The table designer will usually 'cope' with FK relationships - I believe it drops them and then after creating a new table containing the data of the original + additional columns etc. it drops the original, renames the new table and then re-establishes the relationships.  In this case, it looks like the last step failed.  One major benefit of having the change script is that you will then have the "recreate the FKs" code in your hands should the script fail part way through.

Comment: That must be it. Seems like the only way to handle it was a table replacement, which includes dropping all relations. Never had an error with that, though.

Comment: I just figured something out: I don't get the error or any problems if I drop the fulltext index first and recreate it after. That's error prone though (easy to forget). This is really bugging me.

Comment: If you're sure you've got the latest version of Management Studio, log a bug with Microsoft, Alex.

Comment: I would take a a look at the Constraints you are setting...

Also, review your table design.  :)

Comment: @OMG Ponies, don't you mean that the other way around? You can't delete data (at least not in a specific order) with FKs currently active.

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same kind of problem. As Will A said, the management studio will do the following steps to update a table and its foreign keys:

1. Create a new table called temp_
2. Copy contents from old table into new
3. Drop all constraints, indexes and foreign keys
4. Drop old table
5. Rename new table to be = old table
6. Recreate the foreign keys, indexes and constraints

I may have the first 3 in the wrong order but you get the idea.
In my case I've lost entire tables not just the foreign keys. Personally I don't like the way it does it as it can be VERY time consuming to have to recreate indexes on a table with lots of data in. If its a small change I usually do it myself in T-SQL.

Review the change script before it executes it, make sure it looks sensible.

@OMGPonies, why can't you drop a foreign key if there is data in the table? Of course you can. There are only restrictions on creating foreign keys on tables with data but that is only if it breaks the constraint. However even that can be avoided by using the WITH NOCHECK option when creating the key. Yes I know it'll break when you try to update a broken result set.

Comment: Yep, SSMS is pretty dumb when it comes to applying changes (I'm not insulting it by saying dumb - in this case I mean it applies changes through brute force), so if you want to have any sense of control over the changes, you're better off writing the T-SQL to apply the changes manually.